# Read a file's content in Python|PHP

Tags: php, python

I have 100+ save file of `omnigraffle`, need to write a script to read then change its content.

Example one:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/97cec5err3qubgq/test.graffle?dl=0

I can open it by `TextMate`, file's content is in xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ActiveLayerIndex</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>ApplicationVersion</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.omnigroup.OmniGraffle6</string>
        <string>163.7.0.243167</string>
    </array>
    <key>AutoAdjust</key>
    <true/>
    <key>BackgroundGraphic</key>
    <dict>...
```

So i write code to read and write that file in Python

```
contents = open(filename).read()
print contents
```

Result is

```
?]Ys?8~N~?֯IxgO?Gbg}?%?;)Wm?$sB
4???=?z?;F.??l??h?O????q??ش7~?z???ݓ???{??s#?8=?><?il4??Nx?????6N??o???;?hl?0?o????[XP???VF?Ӑ$d????&?????&i=????????o6??ǭN??w???????Ͷ?+/t}FF$?????
?yװ5???aWT??pT?ۥ??v??r???O??Û?u٣GR?)?I!o?~MK??|7??)[)c?'2;|@g#1?J/?!??Jo?X;ؿ??I??t%L?2Jy&?]?;)ЧC^?D????ܑ_`
????{?l?????h????]?7.?y?]7      ?&?
```

So how can we read that file in Python/PHP?

Comment: seems like you need to mess with [string encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file in the link you give is compressed with `gzip`, either as it is stored, or compressed by dropbox when being downloaded to save space.

Either run the `gunzip` command on the file before using it, or use the python [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) module:

```
import gzip
with gzip.open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank @Simon Fraser . I should try to unzip that first : |